# Is creating a new table from scratch to support new query a common pratice in cassandra

Tags: cassandra

Currently, we have the following table, which enables us to perform query based on day.

```
CREATE TABLE events_by_day(
    ...
    traffic_type text,
    device_class text,
    country text,
    ...
    yyyymmdd text,
    event_type text,
    the_datetime timeuuid,
    PRIMARY KEY((yyyymmdd, event_type), the_datetime));

create index index_country on events (country);
create index index_traffic_type on events (traffic_type);
create index index_device_class on events (device_class);
```

The following queries are being supported.

```
select * from events where yymmdd = '20160303' and event_type in ('view');
select * from events where yymmdd = '20160303' and event_type in ('lead', 'view', 'sales');
select * from events where yymmdd = '20160303' and event_type = 'lead' and country = 'my' and device_class = 'smart' and traffic_type = 'WEB' ALLOW FILTERING;
```

When we need a data more than a day, we will perform the query multiple times. Say, I need "view" data from 1st of March 2016 till 3rd of March 2016, I will query 3 times.

```
select * from events where yymmdd = '20160301' and event_type in ('view');
select * from events where yymmdd = '20160302' and event_type in ('view');
select * from events where yymmdd = '20160303' and event_type in ('view');
```

Currently, all these fit well into our requirement.

However, in the future, let's say we have a new requirement, we need "view" data from 2013 till 2016.

Instead of querying it 1460 times (365 days * 4 years) , is it a common practice for us to create a whole new empty table like

```
CREATE TABLE events_by_year(
    ...
    traffic_type text,
    device_class text,
    country text,
    ...
    yyyy text,
    event_type text,
    the_datetime timeuuid,
    PRIMARY KEY((yyyy, event_type), the_datetime));
```

and then fill up the data with large data from `events_by_day` (which might takes several days to finish the insertion as `events_by_day` table already has many rows)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it a common practice for us to create a whole new empty table?

Yes it is.  This is called "Query Based Modeling," and it is quite common in Cassandra.  While Cassandra scales and performs well, it does not offer much in the way of query flexibility.  So to get around that, instead of using ill-performing methods (secondary indexes, ALLOW FILTERING) to query an existing table, the table is commonly duplicated with a different PRIMARY KEY.  Basically, you are trading disk space for performance.

Not to self-promote or anything, but I gave a talk on this subject at the last Cassandra Summit.  You may find the slides helpful: [Escaping Disco Era Data Modeling](http://www.slideshare.net/aploetz/escaping-disco-era-data-modeling)

Speaking of performance, using the `IN` keyword on a partition key has been proven to be just as bad as using a secondary index.  You'll get much better performance with 3 parallel queries, as opposed to this: `event_type in ('lead', 'view', 'sales')`.

Additionally, your last query is using `ALLOW FILTERING` which is something you should never do on a production system, because it will result in a scan of your entire table, and several of your nodes.

For ideal performance, it is best to ensure that your queries target a specific data partition.  This way, you will only hit a single node, and not introduce extraneous network traffic into the equation.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is yes. It is common to roll up weekly, monthly, yearly data in to new tables so that it can be queried more efficiently.

It also would be better to, for example, keep a rolling aggregation that runs daily (could be another suitable time period depending on your data and requirements) and calculates these values, rather than waiting until you need them and then running a process that takes a few days.